# Ejecutar script PHP que realice alguna acción y cerrar automáticamente la pestaña

Tags: php

De PHP voy justico así que necesito toda vuestra ayuda. En un SQL Server tengo la siguiente tabla

```
USE [Pruebas]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.Tabla1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Tabla1
GO
CREATE TABLE Tabla1 (Cliente smallint, Nombre varchar(20) )
GO
```

y este procedimiento almacenado

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Inserta_Tabla1]
    @Cliente AS smallint, @Nombre AS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Tabla1 VALUES(@Cliente, @Nombre)
/* así lo podemos probar
EXEC [SP_Inserta_Tabla1] 1,'Pepe'
SELECT * FROM Tabla1
*/
END
```

a los clientes les envío un email que contiene el cuerpo en formato html así

```
<table><form  method="post">
<tr>
<td><a href="http://localhost/index.php">ClickAqui</a></td>
<td>Pedro</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://localhost/index.php">ClickAqui</a></td>
<td>Juan</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://localhost/index.php">ClickAqui</a></td>
<td>Mary</td>
</tr>
</form></table>
```

para que ellos den en el link y eso llame al script php como este

```
<?php

$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Pruebas;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;";
$usuario = "usuario";
$clave="contra";
$con=odbc_connect($dsn, $usuario, $clave);
if (!$con){
    exit("<strong>Ha ocurrido un error tratando de conectarse con el origen de datos.</strong>");
}   
$arreglo = [1,'Pedro'];
$stmt = odbc_prepare($con, "{call SP_Inserta_Tabla1(?,?)}");
$res = odbc_execute($stmt, $arreglo);
exit();

?>
```

todo lo anterior funciona y me inserta en Tabla1.

Lo que necesito es que una vez que se haya ejecutado el procedimiento el script cierre la pestaña que lo ha "llamado" o sea la que lo contiene automáticamente. He probado con varios ejemplos que he encontrado y que no mencionaré porque son varios y se encuentran fácilmente en Google, algunos proponen un botón o link que cierre pero nada me ha funcionado.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Probaste a ejecutar el script php por ajax devolviendo una respuesta, y que dependiendo esa respuesta haga lo que necesites, en ese caso cerrar la pestaña por medio de js ?

Comment: Como dice @David, yo usaría ajax para hacer esa funcionalidad. Siempre que puedas ejecutar javascript en el cliente de correo.

Comment: gracias a los dos pero no tengo ni idea de hacer algo con ajax, así que me toca "googlear" un poco más